# Using C# WCF REST Service with JSP Servlet

Tags: wcf, web-services, json, jsp, rest

I've created a simple WCF REST Service. It only has one method that returns a JSON string of an employee object.

I'm fairly new to designing web services... What do I need to do in order for a JSP Servlet to invoke that method, retrieve the data, and display the data?

Do I need to generate WSDL or can I simply call http://localhost:8080/TestService/Employee and deserial the JSON string?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With a REST service there is no WSDL, that is a WS-* and SOAP artifact. So you just call the service URL with something like the WebClient, HttpClient or HttpWebRequest and process the response.